# Theory building with Factor Analysis

Tags: factor-analysis

I have a dataset with 95 predictors and a binary response. Many of the predictors have high correlations, so I did Factor Analysis and identified 29 latent factors (most of which make logical sense). From these scores of the fit, I ran a Logistic Regression on the binary response which is satisfactorily significant.

My question is: Is it ok to then look at the values of coefficients of the significant factors, then look at how the original predictors are correlated to the factors and infer a theory?

For instance, is it ok to see that Factor1 is positively correlated with the positive value of the binary response, and the original predictors 1 and 3 are positively correlated with Factor1, but predictor 2 is negatively correlated with Factor1 so... then infer a theory as to why.

Somehow this feels contrived. I am trying to chain correlations back to the original predictors. Thank you.

Comment: Without chain is better than with chain.

Comment: But how to build a theory without looking at the original predictors? I am not just interested in prediction, but also inference.

Comment: With 3 variables $Y, X_1, X_2$, one model is $Y=\beta_0 +\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+\epsilon$, another is $f_1=c_1X_1+c_2X_2$ and $Y=\alpha_0 + \alpha_1 f_1 +e = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1_c_1 X_1+ alpha_1c_2 X_2 + e$. Then think about which one is better.